# Highcharts complex bar chart design with circular annotation or secondary legend

Tags: highcharts

[image]

Using Highcharts, I have implemented the basic bar chart and the legend on the bottom of this design. However, I am trying to figure out how to do the circles with the values.
Looking at annotations but this is not next to the point. Or somehow do a second legend?

Any advice on the best approach on this with highcharts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an annotation in any place on the chart. Example:

```
    annotations: [{
        labels: [{
            shape: 'circle',
            overflow: 'allow',
            text: '1',
            padding: 50,
            point: {
                x: 200,
                y: 400
            }
        }]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8ucke60o/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels.point